# Bootstrap 4 - padding between rows and others (768px width)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying decrease padding between rows, becouse there has appeared a gap, which I can't remove.

[image]

Another gaps are between h1 and span

[image]

I tried use css by @media (max-width: 768px) to remove these ones, but unsuccesfully.

Here is my code.

```css
.row.row-container {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.octicon.octicon-check {
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.box h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.box span {
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row.row-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .octicon.octicon-check {
    font-size: 38px;
    padding-top: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2   sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0  box">
      <h3>Piaskowanie</h3>
      <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.
                </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2    sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3>Endodencja</h3>
      <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2   sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3>Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
      <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2   sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3>Piaskowanie</h3>
      <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2   sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3>Endodencja</h3>
      <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pt-2   sercive-icon">
      <i class="octicon octicon-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3>Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
      <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0  box">
                <h3 id= "test">Piaskowanie</h3>
                <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box" >
                <h3 id= "test">Endodencja</h3>
                <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
                <h3 id= "test">Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
                <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
                <h3 id= "test">Piaskowanie</h3>
                <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.</span>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
                <h3 id= "test">Endodencja</h3>
                <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
                <h3 id= "test">Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
                <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

use this with the above css, what I understood is the div's related to octavia were adding those gaps - so i removed those and made small changes to make it look good. please check

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the .octicon is giving you the extra space between rows as your padding-top on `.row .row-container` is working.

Removing the padding-left from the .octicon succeeds in reducing the extra gap between rows.

```
.octicon.octicon-check{
  font-size: 38px;
  /*padding-left: 22px;*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row.row-container {}

.octicon.octicon-check {
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.box h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.box span {
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row.row-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .octicon.octicon-check {
    font-size: 38px;
    padding-top: 22px;
  }
}

#test {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0  box">
      <h3 id="test">Piaskowanie</h3>
      <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.
                </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3 id="test">Endodencja</h3>
      <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3 id="test">Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
      <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-container mt-4 ">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3 id="test">Piaskowanie</h3>
      <span>Szybki i bezbolesny zabieg polegający na usunięciu osadu kamienia nazębnego
                    za pomocą strumienia wody pod ciśnieniem.</span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3 id="test">Endodencja</h3>
      <span>Bezbolesne leczenie chorej tkanki zęba, z użyciem nowoczesnego mikroskopu i endometru.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 p-0 box">
      <h3 id="test">Wypełnianie zębów</h3>
      <span>Wypełnienie ubytku materiałem plastycznym, lub wypełnienie ubytku pracami protetycznym.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```